# Usage of atomic integer in a shared data

Tags: c, multithreading, integer, atomic, pid

I was studying OS and synchronizing and I got an idea about dealing with this shared data without synchronizing but I am not sure if it will work.Here is the code

Now,the race condition is obviously the increment and decrement in a shared data.But what if the integer variable was atomic?I think I read something about this when I just a beginner in CS so question might not be perfect.As far as I remember it was blocking something to prevent the increment and decrement at the same time.Now,I am a bit confused about this because if the atomic variables really worked there would not be any need to find synchronization methods for simple codes like this one.

Note:Code is removed since it just changes the focus of people and answer provides enough info

Comment: Now your question is complete question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, the code is indeed not safe to call concurrently, so there must be some kind of syncronization that prevents this.

Now, concerning the idea to make `num_processes` atomic, that could work. It wouldn't be a simple substitution though, in particular comparing to the max and incrementing must be done atomically and not in two steps, otherwise you still have a race condition. In particular, the following steps must be prevented:

1. Thread A checks if the limit is reached, which it isn't.
2. Thread B checks if the limit is reached, which it isn't.
3. Thread B increments the PID counter.
4. Thread A increments the PID counter.

Each step in and of itself is atomic, but obviously that didn't help preventing a PID overflow. Instead, the code must check if the counter is not at the limit and then increment it atomically. This is also a common task (compare and increment), so you should easily find existing code examples.

However, I'm pretty sure this isn't all code that is involved and some other code (e.g. in `get_processID()` or the code that releases a PID) could still require a lock around the whole.

Comment: The code in the question is an easy question about the race condition and writing locks to prevent it.
I got your point (I think.)Atomic things must be indivisible so comparing and increment must be done with a single function.Can you elaborate it more.By the way I already accept your answer as a legitimate one since it confirmed what I thought but a little more information would be good.

Comment: I tried to illustrate how using non-atomic testing and incrementing causes a race condition.

Comment: Comparing and incrementing can be effectively done in a signle step if there is an atomic compare-exchange operation available.

Answer (score 1):

For your code, synchronization is not necessary at all because here `num_processes` is incremented and decremented by only one process i.e. Parent process.And also `num_processes` is not a shared variable here. To create shared variable you have to first learn about `shmget()` and `shmat()` function in UNIX.
And race condition arises if two or more processes want to access a shared memory.An operation will be atomic if that operation is going to executed entirely (i.e. no switching) or not at all. For example
Consider increment operator on a shared data. This operator is not atomic. Because if go to the lower level instruction for increment operator then this operation is performed in several steps as:

```
1. First load the value of variable in some register.
2. Add one with that loaded value and now result will be in some temporary register.
3. Store this result in the memory location / register that is pointed by that variable on which increment is performed.
```

Now As you can see this operation is done in three step. So if there is any switching to another process before completion of these three steps then it leads to undesired results. For more you can read about race condition from this link http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/race-conditions-and-critical-sections.html. As from above you can see that `add, store, load` instructions are atomic because it will be performed entirely or not at all considering there is no power failure any system failure. So to perform `increment operation` atomic we need to do some synchronization either using `semaphores` or `monitors`. These all are software synchronization technique. I think now you will be clear on this topic..

Comment: I understood you about atomic part but I am pretty sure this includes a race condition.Because in the comments it says that the implementation of fork() calls this function which will make two processes.I wanted to give as minimal information as possible without misdirecting the question since the question is more about atomic values than forking.But you are right and I will add that to question right now.

Comment: I'm afraid your assumptions are wrong, @Shiv. At least mine were that the code is kernel-level code, so it is shared between all processes. Also, since this is example code and not part of an existing, full OS kernel, things like shared memory support may not even be available.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Please explain me where am i wrong...so that I will correct  that and I will understand about this...

Comment: If this runs in kernel space (I assume it, I don't know it myself), then it is shared between processes and could be called concurrently. In any case, I'm sure that the question was based on the assumption that the code *is* called concurrently.